# Node.js - Redis tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

How do you use the node.js redis library, what are the core concepts of redis and what does all the redis functions do, e.g. hset, hget etc? Could I have some example.

Comment: @lwburk well yes, I've found lot's  auto-generated 'documentation' listing every function without explaining it's unique concept

Comment: this pdf 'the little redis book' helped me http://openmymind.net/redis.pdf

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> How do you use the nodejs redis
>   library

Check out [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and its [examples](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/tree/master/examples).

> what are the core concepts of redis

You should look at [redis data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) in order to get a bigger picture of its concepts and data types.

> what does all the redis functions do

Try to look at [this introduction](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) in order to better understand its [commands](http://redis.io/commands).

Comment: the tutorial link doesn't seem to be working any longer

Comment: It's a shame that the tutorial link is no longer working since it was one of the best tutorials in the wild. I changed it to redis data types.

Answer (score 8):

The book [Learning Node](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024606.do) has *Chapter 9 Structured Data with Node and Redis*.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the [redis documentation](http://redis.io/documentation).

And here is the [nodejs documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/).

What you're using in nodejs should just be a redis-driver. So using redis in nodejs is the same as using redis in any other environment.